# Mysql_real_escape_string...is there an auto setting else where?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mysql-real-escape-string

Got an odd situation here.  On my local mysql database (v5.1.41), I am required to use this escape command if I am to handle users' quotation syntaxs without any problems. However I cannot use this command on my web server's mysql database (v5.0.91-community). If this command is used on the web server (apache v2.2.13), an extra slash syntax is added to the user's quotation syntax, thus if I remove the mysql_real_escape_string command, inputs with quotation marks will have no problems being inserted into the database.

So I was wondering, apart from php, is there a setting within apache (v2.2.13) or within mysql itself that can automatically deal with quotation syntax such as PHP's mysql_real_escape_string command?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Words not helping. Put examples.

Comment: Disable `magic_quotes_gpc` in `php.ini`

Answer (score 6):

This is probably due to [Magic Quotes](http://php.net/security.magicquotes). [Disable or remove them](http://php.net/security.magicquotes.disabling), they are a well-meant but also annoying feature.

Comment: Another PHP setting that must die.

Answer (score 2):

It means the php setting `magic_quotes_gpc` is enabled on the server. It's deprecated, and there's a way to work around it - by removing the slashes at the beginning of your code:

```
<?php
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    function magicQuotes_awStripslashes(&$value, $key) {$value = stripslashes($value);}
    $gpc = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    array_walk_recursive($gpc, 'magicQuotes_awStripslashes');
}
```

Comment: It's usually better to just not have PHP screw up your data in the first place.

Comment: I agree, but there are times when you don't have access to php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommand you to use [filter_input](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php) to get your user data as it does not care about magic_quotes, and parameterized queries to do your database job (see [mysqli](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)).